# When doing long runs, why do we need to wait a day after a work out?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-training-plan

When doing long runs, athletes often use ‘cumulative fatigue’ to train their fast twitch muscle fibres, which are recruited when the slow twitch fibres are fatigued. Most likely, all training plans have long runs at least one day following a fatiguing workout.

*Wouldn't it be more efficient to do the long run on the same day after interval training?*

For example, if we were to do 4 × 4-minute intervals, the total workout time would be around 45 minutes, including warm-up and cool-downs. So we should expect the long run to be around 45 minutes, instead of 90 minutes if we were to perform it on a separate day.

Comment: I was going to answer your question, then I recognised that I was unsure about exactly what you were asking. Would you be able to clarify the latter part of the last paragraph?

Comment: Let's say we usually do 90 minute runs. If the workout counts as 45 minutes, we'll need to extend it with an easy run of only 45 minutes while skipping next day's run.

Comment: I hope my latest edit still reflects the nature of your query, which I have to say has got me thinking and piqued my interest more than I thought it would. I will get back to you after some more thought, and hopefully others will have something to contribute too.